# Nested RecyclerView does not load until i touch my search view

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I'm trying to use a nested recycler view to show some products from Firestore in a home fragment that is similar to play store.
the screen doesn't have an action bar. I have used Search View inside a layout and following that the Nested Recycler View comes. I have a Search View i.e `iconifiedByDefault="true"`.
My Recycler View is not loading until I click on the Search View.
The same thing happens when I use `iconifiedByDefault="false"`.

**XML code for home fragment:**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/search_layout"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/srchView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/searchview_background"
                    app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
                    app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:queryHint="Search by product name.."
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp">
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/parentView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

**HomeFragment.class**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements Serializable{
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ImageView cartIcon;
    SearchView srchView;

    RecyclerView parentView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter parentAdapter;
    ArrayList<ParentModel> parentModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager parentLaoutManager;

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        parentView = view.findViewById(R.id.parentView);

        addData();
        parentLaoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        parentView.setLayoutManager(parentLaoutManager);
        parentAdapter = new ParentAdapter(parentModelArrayList, getActivity());
        parentModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        parentView.setAdapter(parentAdapter);
        parentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }

    private void addData() {
        parentModelArrayList.clear();
        parentModelArrayList.add(new ParentModel("Tasty Snacks"));
        parentModelArrayList.add(new ParentModel("Personal Care"));
    }

}
```

**ParentAdapter.class**

```
public class ParentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ParentAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<ParentModel> parentModelList;
    Activity activity;

    public ParentAdapter(List<ParentModel> parentModelList, Activity activity) {
        this.parentModelList = parentModelList;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.parent_view_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ParentModel currentItem = parentModelList.get(position);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(activity,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        holder.prntRView.setLayoutManager(lm);
        ArrayList<ProductDataModel> prdModellist = new ArrayList<>();
        ProductAdapter productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(holder.prntRView.getContext(),prdModellist);
        holder.prntRView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
        holder.title.setText(currentItem.categoryText());
        holder.viewAllBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("btn id", currentItem.categoryText());
                showLanding(currentItem.categoryText());
            }
        });

        FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
        if (parentModelList.get(position).categoryText().equals("Tasty Snacks")) {
            firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            firebaseFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).whereEqualTo(CONDITION).get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot: task.getResult()) {
                                    prdModellist.add(new ProductDataModel(
                                        (String) queryDocumentSnapshot.get("productimage"),
                                        (String) queryDocumentSnapshot.get("productname"),
                                        (String) queryDocumentSnapshot.get("description"),
                                        (Long) queryDocumentSnapshot.get("price"),
                                        (Long) queryDocumentSnapshot.get("discount")
                                    ));
                                }
                            } else {
                                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                System.out.println(error);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
        if (parentModelList.get(position).categoryText().equals("Personal Care")) {
            firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            firebaseFirestore.collection(COLLECTION).whereEqualTo(CONDITION2).get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot: Task.getResult()) {
                                    prdModellist.add(new ProductDataModel(
                                       (String) queryDocumentSnapshot.get("productimage"),
                                       (String) queryDocumentSnapshot.get("productname"),
                                       (String) queryDocumentSnapshot.get("description"),
                                       (Long) queryDocumentSnapshot.get("price"),
                                       (Long) queryDocumentSnapshot.get("discount")
                                    ));
                                }
                            } else {
                                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                System.out.println(error);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    }
    

    private void showLanding(String categoryText) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (categoryText){
            case "Tasty Snacks":
            case "Personal Care":
                intent = new Intent(activity,ProductsLandingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",categoryText);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return parentModelList.size();
    }
    
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
        TextView title;
        MaterialButton viewAllBtn;
        RecyclerView prntRView;
    
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prntTitle);
            viewAllBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewAllBtn);
            prntRView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prntRView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Until i click my Search view the data is not loading in child view which has a list of products.